# How to use tlsSocket.renegotiate(options, callback) in Node.js 0.11.8 and higher

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ssl, certificate

I'm new to node.js and I have a simple https server running. Now when a user requests a certain context path the server should initiate a SSL renegotiation and ask for a client certificate authentication. I saw that this is supported in node.js 0.11.8 and higher.

I tried this so far, but a renegotiation is not happening. Not even an error is thrown.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var optSsl = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server/keys/server.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server/certs/server.crt'),
   ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca/ca.crt'),
   requestCert: false,
   rejectUnauthorized: true,
   ciphers: 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS',
   honorCipherOrder: true
};

var optClientAuth = {
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = https.createServer(optSsl, function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.on('request', function(req, res){
    console.log('request emitted on ' + req.url);
    if (req.url == '/secure') {
        try {
            var socket = req.connection;
            socket.renegotiate(optClientAuth, function(err){
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(req.connection.getPeerCertificate());
                } else {
                    console.log(err.message);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
});

server.on('secureConnection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Secure connection established');
});

server.listen(8443);
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: I added the code to my question...

Comment: did you ever figure out how to use this?

Comment: Yes, (after a long time) it turned out that I messed up with the certificates. I created a new root, issued two certs, one for the server and one for the client, signed by the root. And now it works. Unfortunately it seems that you cannot load multiple CA certificates for presenting all possible client certs - or I did something wrong (again)

Comment: So the code works? I am not sure if you made any changes to the code to make it work... Thanks

Comment: @lpbug see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code which works for me.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var constants = require('constants');

var optSsl = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./ca.crt'),
    passphrase: "very_secret",
    agent: false,
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ciphers: 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS',
    honorCipherOrder: true,
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2
};

var optClientAuth = {
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = https.createServer(optSsl);

server.on('request', function(req, res){
    console.log('request emitted on ' + req.url);
    var socket = req.connection;
    if (req.url == '/secure') {
        var result = socket.renegotiate(optClientAuth, function(err){
            if (!err) {
                console.log(req.connection.getPeerCertificate());

                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end("Authenticated Hello World\n");
            } else {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("Secured Hello World\n");
    };
});

server.listen(8443);
```